# import can not be resolved (android developer sample)

Tags: android, eclipse, admob, google-play-services

1. I downloaded [sample from android developer](http://developer.android.com/training/monetization/ads-and-ux.html) site.
2. set up [android-support-v7-appcompact according to developer site](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library).
3. Set up [google-play-services_lib](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup).(sdk\extras\google\google_play_services) But the three imports can't be resolved.

   `import com.google.ads.Ad;
   import com.google.ads.AdListener;
   import com.google.ads.AdView;`

Cleaned the project and restart the eclipse does nutting. Please can any one help me.

Comment: did you get the froyo release of google play service ? if, there is no ads support in this version. have to take the "main" release that include ads but is only Android > 2.2 i think.

Comment: @Hacketo, yes(sdk\extras\google\google_play_services_froyo).

Comment: Did you configure the buildpath?

Comment: @Nabin, configure means right clicking on the project and adding?

Comment: right click on project>configure build path>add jar>select the required jar file

Comment: @Nabin, yes i have done. And just now i changed from froyo but not resolved (sdk\extras\google\google_play_services).

Answer (score 1):

"Google Play Services Froyo" Release is not including the ads support.

Comment: just now i changed but not resolved (sdk\extras\google\google_play_services).

Answer (score 0):

`Google Play Services Froyo` release is not including the ads support,
Have to take the "main" release.

And change the namespaces of the ads import : `com.google.android.gms.ads`, see : http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary.html

Comment: just now i changed but not resolved (sdk\extras\google\google_play_services).

Comment: have the main release in this folder ?, and manifest updated with minSdk 9 i think.

Comment: I don't no main release. Can you say it for me.

Comment: If your are on eclipse you should have a shared eclipse project for the google play service , see : https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw at the 3. Is your project configured like that ?

Comment: yes i have done according to the document i suggested. these 2 imports are resolved but still 3 another imports not resolved import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;

Comment: then imports should be namespaced like that : com.google.android.gms.ads.* , see : http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary.html